# Starting service from AlertDialog in onClick. Sometime service is not starting

Tags: android, android-service, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I have follow class for showing message from the social website:

```
public class MessageDialog extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    final LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_dialog, null);

    builder.setView(view)
            .setNeutralButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), RequestService.class);
                    //intent.putExtra("data", some_extra_data);
                    getActivity().startService(intent);
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("GoTo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //GoTo();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    if(getActivity() != null)
    getActivity().finish();
}

}
```

Above class is simplified, of course. This message showing from `FragmentActivity` that starting from background service.
I found that in some cases buttons of `AlertDialog` (message dialog) are not execute code inside onClick. For example, service `RequestService.class` is not starting only the next day and only for first time. After showing dialog again it is working fine.

FragmentActivity class where from AlertDialog is showing:

```
public class MyFragmentDialog extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    switch (extras.getInt("action", 0))
    {
        case SHOW_MSG_DIALOG:
            // 1. Message case
            String json = extras.getString("data");

            if(json != null)
            {
                try {
                    JSONObject mail = new JSONObject(json);

                    MessageDialog msgDialog = new MessageDialog();
                    msgDialog.setData(mail);
                    msgDialog.show(fm, "msgDialog");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    finish();
                }
            }
            else
            finish();

        break;

        // 2. case
        // ...

        // 3. case
        // ...

        case 0:
            // exit default
        break;
    }

}
}
```

Have I missing something?

**SOLVED:** Bug was in a AppCompatEditText that broken my json string. Android... a peace of shirt)

Comment: can you please add the code from were you called the Dialog Fragment

Comment: I add the FragmentActivity class that call message dialog

Comment: try my below answer hope it wiil help you.

Comment: OK, I'm found and reproduce a bug. This bug happen when MessageDialog is already shown and if press Power device button and then unlock phone, repeat this procedure a few time and then click on MessageDialog button (send) then service can't get correct data and server response: auth failed...

Comment: OK, I'm completely found what cause the bug. Bug was produced by using `Base64.encodeToString(JSONData.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);`. When I take a look at JSON sent from device it was something like that: {"data":{"message_id":"1991524","text":"КИРИЛЛИЦА4/44/``444/.44444//-"'FB##'&WF#&V#&F֖fG6V"'72###7Ffb'&WFB#'6VE&fD6r'`‌​. So, now I searching for a solution. Seems bug in using cyrrylic letters.

Comment: **Solution**: use this: `URLEncoder.encode(Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP),"UTF-8");` if you want send data as parameter to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after many tries I'm found why my ServerRequestService doesn't want to work. Base64 encoded string was sent as part of URL as parameter. If I send string containing cyrillic symbols it's broken Base64 and JSON sended to the server now is not correct. Solution was use `URLEncoder.encode(Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP),"UTF-8");` to encode URL string parameter to avoid corrupted data. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

try this,

Create a Constructor in Dialog Fragment.

```
public class MessageDialog extends DialogFragment {

  private Activity mActivity;
     public MessageDialog(Activity mActivity) {
            this.mActivity = mActivity;

        }

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
    final LayoutInflater inflater = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_dialog, null);

    builder.setView(view)
            .setNeutralButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, RequestService.class);
                    //intent.putExtra("data", some_extra_data);
                    mActivity.startService(intent);
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("GoTo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //GoTo();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    if(mActivity != null)
    mActivity.finish();
}
```

And Call the Fragment.

```
MessageDialog msgDialog = new MessageDialog(YourActivity.this);
msgDialog.setData(mail);
msgDialog.show(fm, "msgDialog");
```

Comment: **Pradeep**, thank for your answer and for your help, I'm really need this. I'll check your solution and mark as solution or write a comment again. It's need a time to test. But for now I only can thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, `onAttach` method does not exist in a FragmentActivity

Comment: Now there are no errors while compiling and runing app. But it need a time to check for complete test. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but IDE say: Error: `This fragment should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments)`. If setting Dialog to the Activity really can help fix my problem may be it's needs to be setted through the public fields of the DialogFragment?